# TParameter has no attribute "value"

Tags: uproot

I have this TParameter (a Model_TParameter_3c_double_3e__v2 to be precise) which I am trying to access via its "value" attribute which I have seen to use via the docs [here](https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uproot.behaviors.TParameter.TParameter_3c_integer_3e_.html)

```
uproot.open("pathtoTParameter").value
```

But that doesn't work and spits out:

```
AttributeError: 'Model_TParameter_3c_double_3e__v2' object has no attribute 'value'
```

I have also read it in via root using the standard member function GetVal() and everything seemed to be working fine there.

Am I missing something? Cheers

Comment: Somehow, it's failing to be recognized; I'll have to look at an example file. Please submit it as a GitHub Issue with a file that demonstrate the bug. Meanwhile, the member can be accessed as `obj.member("fVal")`; it's the convenience method that's missing. (https://github.com/scikit-hep/uproot4/blob/390b29b40d57562cd864719885c584c42a006e23/src/uproot/behaviors/TParameter.py#L58)